# ActiveMQ / Camel : spawn multiple routes, wait for all to be completed

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm new to activeMQ / Camel, so please bear with me.

In a camel route, I use a splitter to spawn multiple sub routes. Each one of this routes will use some external APIs to do some job, and poll until job is done. I'm that far.

Now I need to trigger a last action to collect the result of all of these routes. How would I do that the Camel / AMQ way ?

I was thinking of posting a message in each sub-route to an AMQ queue, but I haven't found a way yet to wait for the N messages to be received in that queue before consuming it in my final Camel route.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to collect all the results from the splitter sub-routes and execute some action on those results after all the sub-routes are completed then you can use an aggregation strategy(https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/aggregate-eip.html) on the splitter.

By using an aggregation strategy, the Exchange after the split will contain the results of all the sub-routes.

Example using the Java DSL:

```
.split(expression, new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy())
   ...
.end()
```

The *GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy* aggregates all split Exchanges into a list. You can use another predefined aggregation strategy if you need, or you can create a custom one by extending  *org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregationStrategy*.